# how to specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions on qemu

Tags: qemu

As I put command like this,

`qemu-system-i386 -nographic -serial mon:stdio-hbd fs.img xv6.img -smp 1 -m 512`

then the warning that I posted below comes out.

`WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'fs.img' and probing guessed raw.          Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.          Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.`

how should I change the command to fix this?

After I searched in google, I think I got a hint that I should add format=raw.
But the problem is I don't get where to put it, and why the problem was made in the first place.

Comment: Already asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235461/how-to-resolve-specify-the-raw-format-explicitly-to-remove-the-restrictions

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, that's a Warning message, it's telling you that QEMU cannot determine the image format and it guessed that the format is raw. When QEMU guess it can be dangerous as it can apply restrictions in the writing operations. So it's telling you that you should specify the format.

To specify the format you can use -drive, in your case I think this command would work:

`qemu-system-i386 -nographic -serial mon:stdio -hdb fs.img -hda xv6.img -smp 1 -m 512 -drive format=raw,file=fs.img,if=virtio`