# Where to Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the warning on qemu

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, qemu, terminal-emulator

I am trying to run a raspberry pi emulator on Ubuntu. I have my unzipped raspberry image named rpi.img and qemu folder all in the rpi directory.

Am running this command:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -m 256 \
  -kernel qemu-rpi-kernel/kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster -hda rpi.img \
  -append "dwc_otq.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/sda2 console=tt1 rootfstype=exr4 elavator=deadline rootwait" \
  -dtb qemu-rpi-kernel versatile-pb-buster.dtb -no-reboot -serial stdio
```

It gives me the warning:

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'rpi.img' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
qemu-system-arm: versatile-pb-buster.dtb: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
```

and the emulator does not start. Where exactly should i specify the "format =raw" i have tried a couple of solutions and i get errors or the same warning.

Thanks

Comment: Answered already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235461/how-to-resolve-specify-the-raw-format-explicitly-to-remove-the-restrictions   Note that the reason QEMU is not starting is not related to the warning about the raw image, though. That is because you've got a space in your argument to the '-dtb' option between 'kernel' and 'versatile' that should probably be a /

Comment: Thanks. It was the space and I had to remove 'console=tt1 rootfstype=exr4 eelevatordeadline rootwait' to get it to work.

Comment: There are at least two typos in that ('tt1' isn't a valid console name, and 'exr4' is a typo for 'ext4'). I'm not sure where you're getting your instructions from, but you need to double-check all this sort of stuff, or better yet cut-and-paste rather than re-typing...